# Blob Trigger : Storage account is not configured

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to make a blob trigger azure function in Visual Studio. I gave the connection string value in the connection string  and the container name in path. But when I run the boilerplate code that is generated I get the error that the storage account is not configured and a warning that

`Warning: Cannot find value named *connection-string-here* in local.settings.json that matches 'connection' property set on 'blobTrigger'. You can run 'func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <functionAppName>' or specify a connection string in local.settings.json.`

Do I have to configure in the local.setting.json aswell?

This is my function currently

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("*container-name*/{name}", Connection = "*connection-string*")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value for `Connection` is the name of the app setting that contains the connection string. It is not the connection string itself.

If you specify 'MyStorage' as the value then you need to have the 'AzureWebJobsMyStorage' property set in `local.setting.json` for local development.

Comment: where should i put the connection string for the storage account in which is the blob that i want a trigger for?

Comment: If you use `MyStorage` then put the connection string in local.setting.json as "AzureWebJobsMyStorage": "your-connection-string".